# Filter numpy 2D Array with multiple conditions

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I've a numpy 2D array as :

```
[
 ['AAPL' Timestamp('2022-03-10 15:00:00') 157.55 159.19 157.13 159.01],
 ['AAPL' Timestamp('2022-03-11 15:00:00') 158.55 159.19 157.13 159.01],
 ['AMZN' Timestamp('2022-03-10 15:00:00') 147.55 159.19 157.13 159.01],
 ['AMZN' Timestamp('2022-03-11 15:00:00') 148.55 159.19 157.13 159.01],
]
```

I want to filter it with 1st and 2nd index i.e rows containing values `'AAPL'` and datetime greater than and equals to `'2022-03-11 15:00:00'` .
How can i achieve this ?

Comment: This is not reproducible. Try copying it and pasting it into python. You get errors. Please share data that can be reproduced. Also consider having a pandas dataframe in the case where columns of the array have different data types

Comment: Is that really a 2d numpy array?  'Timestamp' suggests it is `pandas`.